# Review audit failure

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

Ok,so this was my first review audit failure and I really need to understand why so that I will try not to repeat this mistake in future.

The review in question is [this late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4673823). The answer here is just trying to suggest a link, along with an explanation of what the link contains.

I understand that link only answers are bad but he did tried to tell that there are some tools & you may find them here. Also, I don't think this was the reason for the audit to fail. Can anyone please help me understand?

Comment: So why did you click the "no action needed" button?

Comment: Because he did tried to tell that there are some tools & you may find them here. If he'd provided a list here with links to the same page,would that had been a good answer?(I'm just trying to understand)

Comment: It was selected as an audit because it was flagged as spam or very low quality, then deleted.

Comment: So,what you are trying to tell me is that I should follow the link to every Q/A & check whether that still exists or not? When I'm reviewing I shouldn't be concerned with whether it was already deleted or not. What I should be concerned with is the quality of the answer,right? Whether a sufficient effort has been made to answer the question

Comment: @shaktimaan indeed; and link-only answers shouldn't be kept around

Comment: @JanDvorak: if you look at the profile page, it's fairly obvious that this answer was from a spammer ([take a look at this spammy answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469273/is-there-a-query-tool-for-cassandra-or-other-nosql-dbs-similar-to-qtado-or-nav/22804248#22804248)).

Comment: @OneKitten: But kind sir,I'm not supposed to look at their profile to review a Q/A,right? All I'm supposed to look at is the Q/A & if I don't get enough information there, then click on the _link_ provided for more info.

Comment: @shak, that answer alone was clearly low quality, there was no need to check the profile, it was a link to a tool with no explanation other than "[it has] high performance functionality"

Comment: Even I generally ask the answerer to explain if it was a link only answer, but in this particular case I couldn't understand what more he could have written to explain better. I think I should maybe skip them maybe from now on as I'm still unable to grasp the whole thing as to how to better put up an answer if you are recommending a tool

Comment: I failed that exact same audit today. Without actually clicking on the link it's not possible to see that it is spam. The answer looks helpful.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich It's obvious from just glancing at it that the answer is of low quality and needs some help.  Further investigation makes it clear that it's not just low quality, but spam.  Either way, *some* action was clearly needed.  That you didn't realize this is exactly why it's *a good thing* that you've failed such an audit.  You can either take the opportunity to learn from the mistake that you've made so that you can better review posts in the queue, or stop using the review system.

Comment: @Servy: Audits don't help turning bad reviewers into good reviewers, they just separate them from each other. The reason I fail audits is not that I'm not paying attention or trying to grind my way towards some badges with minimal effort or that I'm just plain evil. The reason is that the criteria I apply for assessing the quality of posts is different from the one that the makers of these audits expect me to apply. Unfortunately, there's no definite guide on how to judge the posts presented in the review queue and the guide lines for Q&As as outlined in the help center are mostly vague.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich You say that they don't help turn bad reviewers into good reviewers, yet you've made it clear that you're not a particularly good reviewer (given that you're approving spam), and you'll need to become a better one in order to participate in the system.  If you become willing to improve and take the time to learn what is and isn't acceptable, you'll become a good reviewer.  If you don't and continue to only apply your own guidelines, you won't be able to continue participating.  The choice is up to you.

Comment: @Servy: I get the feeling, you're not even trying to understand. Me and many other reviewers who fail in audits are absolutely willing to comply with the community guidelines **if we only knew what they were**. So please, try being a little more cooperative and instead of telling us that we should all go to hell (in a roundabout way), just point us to a resource where we can educate ourselves.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich There isn't just one page of information that can tell you everything you need to know to be a good reviewer.  It takes time and experience working with the site to learn what appropriate standards are, have the time to come across different situations, etc.  You can certainly start out with the help center, the FAQ, and some searches through review related content on meta, as a starting point, but of equal importance is to recognize what situations you do and don't know how to handle (so you can `Skip` what you can't fix) and to learn how to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: @Servy: Thank you for your suggestions. However, (as you said yourself) they're a starting point, but not much more. The help center is not of particular help, because it only states what makes a **good** post and not what is **acceptable**. The information given here on meta is scattered and mostly opinion based. Wouldn't it be helpful to have a few wiki-questions (one per qeue) here on meta that explicitly address the things to do and look for in each review queue? I'd be willing to create such questions, but I fear you or others would instantly vote to close.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich As I said, the problem is that there is just too much to discuss to throw it all into a single question.  There *is* an FAQ entry for each queue, as you described, but they're *still* not going to be exhaustive.  To be a good reviewer you need to know how to go out and find answers to your questions of how to handle a given situation because you *can't* find it all on one page.

Comment: @Servy: "There *is* an FAQ entry for each queue" - links please, because I can't find them.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing.  You can just ctrl+F for "Review" on the FAQ index...

Comment: ["At 20 reviews a day limit, one has plenty time to do more thorough check of reviewed posts..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251155/165773)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/262723.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to all of us. The tricky part is that the answer actually looks ok. The link goes to the company that provides the tools mentioned.
The only thing remotely odd is that the link goes to the start page instead of a product page and the use of the term "high-performance", which is promotional. That, and the fact that late answers by low-rep users are always suspicious.

With the information given in the answer, the only thing that separates this answer from a an answer recommending an oracle product or an open source product is... nothing.

The only way to catch this as spam is to check other answers by the same account (or in this case other, deleted, answers on the same question) and I usually don't do that either.

Comment: If you want to avoid failing audits, you can also click through to the original post, and see if it has been deleted. If it has, it's obviously an audit. Or skip the review for anything that has a remote chance of being spam. Because as you say, you can't generally identify them without context and background research.